# Can not communicate with my modem quectel m35 16 ports

Tags: java, serial-port, at-command, modem

I have a program in java that lists the COM ports and determines which is the appropriate speed for each of the ports. I installed rxtx, smslib and even javax comm and also a 32 bit JDK.

My objective is to be able to communicate my modem gsm questel m35 16 COM ports with my program java.
The program lists all the available ports but I cannot communicate with any of them.

Here is the code:

```
   package comm.atcommlib.commands;

   import org.smslib.helper.CommPortIdentifier;
   import org.smslib.helper.SerialPort;

   import java.io.InputStream;
   import java.io.OutputStream;
   import java.util.Enumeration;
   import java.util.Formatter;

   public class CommTest
   {
       private static final String _NO_DEVICE_FOUND = "  no device found";

private final static Formatter _formatter = new Formatter(System.out);

static CommPortIdentifier portId;

static Enumeration<CommPortIdentifier> portList;

static int bauds[] = {2400,4800, 9600, 14400, 19200, 28800, 33600, 38400, 56000, 57600, 115200 };


private static Enumeration<CommPortIdentifier> getCleanPortIdentifiers()
{
    return CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("\nSearching for devices...");
    portList = getCleanPortIdentifiers();


    while (portList.hasMoreElements())
    {
        portId = portList.nextElement();
        if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL)
        {
            _formatter.format("%nFound port: %-5s%n", portId.getName());
            for (int i = 0; i < bauds.length; i++)
            {
                SerialPort serialPort = null;
                _formatter.format("       Trying at %6d...", bauds[i]);
                try
                {
                    InputStream inStream;
                    OutputStream outStream;
                    int c;
                    String response;
                    serialPort = portId.open("SMSLibCommTester", 1971);
                    serialPort.setFlowControlMode(SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_RTSCTS_IN);
                    serialPort.setSerialPortParams(bauds[i], SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
                    inStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
                    outStream = serialPort.getOutputStream();
                    serialPort.enableReceiveTimeout(1000);
                        c = inStream.read();
                    while (c != -1)
                        c = inStream.read();
                    outStream.write('A');
                    outStream.write('T');
                    outStream.write('\r');
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    response = "";
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    c = inStream.read();
                    System.out.println(c);
                    while (c != -1)
                    {
                        sb.append((char) c);
                        c = inStream.read();
                    }
                    response = sb.toString();
                    if (response.indexOf("OK") >= 0)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            System.out.print("  Getting Info...");
                            outStream.write('A');
                            outStream.write('T');
                            outStream.write('+');
                            outStream.write('C');
                            outStream.write('G');
                            outStream.write('M');
                            outStream.write('M');
                            outStream.write('\r');
                            response = "";
                            c = inStream.read();
                            while (c != -1)
                            {
                                response += (char) c;
                                c = inStream.read();
                            }
                            System.out.println(" Found: " + response.replaceAll("\\s+OK\\s+", "").replaceAll("\n", "").replaceAll("\r", ""));
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            System.out.println(_NO_DEVICE_FOUND);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println(_NO_DEVICE_FOUND);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.print(_NO_DEVICE_FOUND);
                    Throwable cause = e;
                    while (cause.getCause() != null)
                    {
                        cause = cause.getCause();
                    }
                    System.out.println(" (" + cause.getMessage() + ")");
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (serialPort != null)
                    {
                        serialPort.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\nTest complete.");
}
 }
```

The program succeeded to connect with another GSM modem (mobile phone) and I manage to connect and communicate with other communication software that uses the COM ports (SMScaster, At Command Tester) but my program n ' does not arrive with this modem ports in particular

Here is the result:

```
  run:

  Searching for devices...

Found port: COM11
   Trying at   2400...  no device found
   Trying at   4800...  no device found
   Trying at   9600...  no device found
   Trying at  14400...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  19200...  no device found
   Trying at  28800...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  33600...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  38400...  no device found
   Trying at  56000...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  57600...  no device found
   Trying at 115200...  no device found

   Found port: COM12
   Trying at   2400...  no device found
   Trying at   4800...  no device found
   Trying at   9600...  no device found
   Trying at  14400...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  19200...  no device found
   Trying at  28800...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  33600...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  38400...  no device found
   Trying at  56000...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  57600...  no device found
   Trying at 115200...  no device found

  Found port: COM14
   Trying at   2400...  no device found
   Trying at   4800...  no device found
   Trying at   9600...  no device found
   Trying at  14400...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  19200...  no device found
   Trying at  28800...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  33600...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  38400...  no device found
   Trying at  56000...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  57600...  no device found
   Trying at 115200...  no device found

  Found port: COM13
   Trying at   2400...  no device found
   Trying at   4800...  no device found
   Trying at   9600...  no device found
   Trying at  14400...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  19200...  no device found
   Trying at  28800...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  33600...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  38400...  no device found
   Trying at  56000...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  57600...  no device found
   Trying at 115200...  no device found

   Found port: COM15
   Trying at   2400...  no device found
   Trying at   4800...  no device found
   Trying at   9600...  no device found
   Trying at  14400...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  19200...  no device found
   Trying at  28800...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  33600...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  38400...  no device found
   Trying at  56000...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  57600...  no device found
   Trying at 115200...  no device found

     Found port: COM16
   Trying at   2400...  no device found
   Trying at   4800...  no device found
   Trying at   9600...  no device found
   Trying at  14400...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  19200...  no device found
   Trying at  28800...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  33600...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  38400...  no device found
   Trying at  56000...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  57600...  no device found
   Trying at 115200...  no device found

    Found port: COM17
   Trying at   2400...  no device found
   Trying at   4800...  no device found
   Trying at   9600...  no device found
   Trying at  14400...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  19200...  no device found
   Trying at  28800...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  33600...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  38400...  no device found
   Trying at  56000...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  57600...  no device found
   Trying at 115200...  no device found

   Found port: COM18
   Trying at   2400...  no device found
   Trying at   4800...  no device found
   Trying at   9600...  no device found
   Trying at  14400...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  19200...  no device found
   Trying at  28800...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  33600...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  38400...  no device found
   Trying at  56000...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  57600...  no device found
   Trying at 115200...  no device found

   Found port: COM19
   Trying at   2400...  no device found
   Trying at   4800...  no device found
   Trying at   9600...  no device found
   Trying at  14400...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  19200...  no device found
   Trying at  28800...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  33600...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  38400...  no device found
   Trying at  56000...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  57600...  no device found
   Trying at 115200...  no device found

    Found port: COM20
   Trying at   2400...  no device found
   Trying at   4800...  no device found
   Trying at   9600...  no device found
   Trying at  14400...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  19200...  no device found
   Trying at  28800...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  33600...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  38400...  no device found
   Trying at  56000...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  57600...  no device found
   Trying at 115200...  no device found

   Found port: COM21
   Trying at   2400...  no device found
   Trying at   4800...  no device found
   Trying at   9600...  no device found
   Trying at  14400...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  19200...  no device found
   Trying at  28800...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  33600...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  38400...  no device found
   Trying at  56000...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  57600...  no device found
   Trying at 115200...  no device found

   Found port: COM22
   Trying at   2400...  no device found
   Trying at   4800...  no device found
   Trying at   9600...  no device found
   Trying at  14400...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  19200...  no device found
   Trying at  28800...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  33600...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  38400...  no device found
   Trying at  56000...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  57600...  no device found
   Trying at 115200...  no device found

   Found port: COM23
   Trying at   2400...  no device found
   Trying at   4800...  no device found
   Trying at   9600...  no device found
   Trying at  14400...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  19200...  no device found
   Trying at  28800...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  33600...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  38400...  no device found
   Trying at  56000...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  57600...  no device found
   Trying at 115200...  no device found

    Found port: COM24
   Trying at   2400...  no device found
   Trying at   4800...  no device found
   Trying at   9600...  no device found
   Trying at  14400...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  19200...  no device found
   Trying at  28800...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  33600...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  38400...  no device found
   Trying at  56000...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  57600...  no device found
   Trying at 115200...  no device found

   Found port: COM25
   Trying at   2400...  no device found
   Trying at   4800...  no device found
   Trying at   9600...  no device found
   Trying at  14400...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  19200...  no device found
   Trying at  28800...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  33600...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  38400...  no device found
   Trying at  56000...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  57600...  no device found
   Trying at 115200...  no device found

   Found port: COM26
   Trying at   2400...  no device found
   Trying at   4800...  no device found
   Trying at   9600...  no device found
   Trying at  14400...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  19200...  no device found
   Trying at  28800...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  33600...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  38400...  no device found
   Trying at  56000...  no device found (javax.comm.UnsupportedCommOperationException: Unsupported baud rate)
   Trying at  57600...  no device found
   Trying at 115200...  no device found

    Test complete.
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig     
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig  
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
   Error 87 SetCommConfig
    BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 minutes 51 seconds)
```

I installed all the drivers provided in the installation cd. I work with netbeans 8.1 under windows 8.1.
I have already looked for speed without success